# NSURL Throws nil exception using mailto:

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, nsurl, openurl

I was trying to open mail on UILabel click event. But its throws fatal error:

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

Code used:

```
func sendMail(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer){
        print("mail::" + self.lblMail.text!) // joe@nts.com is here
        let url = NSURL(string: "mailto:\(self.lblMail.text)")! //url is nil when debugged
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check to make sure `self.lblMail.text` is non-nil before proceeding by unwrapping it with an `if let`:

```
if let email = self.lblMail.text {
    let url = NSURL(string: "mailto:\(email)")!
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
}
```

If you get the error:

> LaunchServices: ERROR: There is no registered handler for URL scheme mailto

Make sure you're running this code on an actual device and not the iOS Simulator.

Comment: Thanks , I m getting the same error. So it means its because I m using a simulator?

Comment: @user2695433 See my updated answer.  Try running on an actual device.

Answer (score 0):

Try 
`let url = NSURL(string: "mailto:\(self.lblMail.text!)")!`

Comment: it shows ERROR: There is no registered handler for URL scheme mailto, Is it because I m using a simulator instead of a device

Comment: but it doesn't crash where it used to, does it?

Comment: yes, I think this is because of simulator usage. the device should handle such an url